# DMV to identify Database Lock scenarios in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, locking, dmv

I have a batch process that runs every night. Once the process completes, I see that there are some records which has not processed completely.
I think I might be encountering a locking scenario while running multiple updates on a single table.

What is the best way to troubleshoot locking in the database using DMVs?
Is there any particular DMV, that I can run in the morning(after the batch has completed) - which will provide me information on the locked processes encountered by the SQL engine,during the nightly run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sys.sysprocesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx)

Contains information about processes that are running on an instance of SQL Server.

The below command will gets you the blocked processes

```
select * from sys.sysprocesses where blocked > 0
```